# Keeping System.Threading.Timer alive without using private member

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection

I'm currently trying to use a `System.Threading.Timer` to fire callbacks for my current class. My current class looks like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
     private Timer _timer;

     public TestClass()
     {
         _timer = new Timer(Callback, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
     }

     private void Callback(object state)
     {
         //Do stuff here
     }
}
```

This attaches `Timer` to the TestClass, and prevents garbage collection. What I'm noticing though, is that resharper likes to bitch and moan that _timer is not being used:

[image]

Now, while I can disable this warning by adding `// ReSharper disable once NotAccessedField.Local` above the _timer, is this the recommended approach?

I've tried `GC.KeepAlive(timer)` instead of adding an implicit reference, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a way to tell the Garbage collector to keep the timer alive for as long as TestClass is alive (Without having ReSharper bitch)?

Comment: There are lots of ways. Did you try, for example, storing the reference in an array or a list? Then the array or list would be used (because you put something in it). But, what's so wrong about just disabling the warning for that local variable? (Note: `GC.KeepAlive()` only applies to the method in which it's used.) You could also use one of the other timer classes, which don't require you to keep a reference. Or even, stop using timer objects , since with `Task.Delay()` and `async`/`await`, you don't need them for most things. There are literally _too many_ possible answers to your question.

Comment: Seems to be the correct way of working with it https://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/07/systemthreadingtimer-constructor-and.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, while I can disable this warning by adding "// ReSharper disable once NotAccessedField.Local" above the _timer, is this the recommended approach?

It is OK to explicitly store a reference to an object when you need it to stay alive.
I see nothing wrong with it. You can always suppress ReSharper warning with comment or just ignore it - that's why it is called a warning, not an error.

Another important thing that you need to understand is that you cannot just forget about your `Timer` when you finish using it and expect GC to stop and collect it.
`System.Threading.Timer` is `IDisposable` and needs to be correctly disposed.

You should implement `IDisposable` pattern for your object too:

```
public class TestClass : IDisposable
{
     private Timer _timer;

     public TestClass()
     {
         _timer = new Timer(Callback, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
     }

     private void Callback(object state)
     {
         //Do stuff here
     }

     public void Dispose() // the simplest IDisposable implementation
     {
         _timer?.Dispose();
     }
}

// Usage:
using (var testClass = new TestClass())
{

}
```

Now, you can be sure that your `Timer` is correctly stopped and disposed right after you stopped using it. 
As a side effect, it solves your "field is not used" warning :)